# How to delete WebAuthn resident keys / discoverable credentials from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webauthn

I have a test webapp that uses passkeys/ WebAuthn, this app requests `requireResidentKey: true`

```
      const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
        challenge: new Uint8Array(base64urldecode(step1.challenge)),
        rp: step1.relayingPartyInfo,
        user: {
          id: new TextEncoder().encode(step1.userInfo.id),
          name: step1.userInfo.name,
          displayName: step1.userInfo.displayName,
        },
        pubKeyCredParams: [
          { alg: -7, type: "public-key" },
          { alg: -257, type: "public-key" },
        ],
        authenticatorSelection: {
          requireResidentKey: true,
        },
        timeout: 60000,
        attestation: "direct",
      };
      const credential = await navigator.credentials.create({
        publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions,
      });
```

When executing this javascript on the chrome client side I get the

[image]

and it successfully registers, `navigator.credentials.create()` returns a `PublicKeyCredential` with `authenticatorAttachment: "platform"` and `.response.clientDataJSON` and `.response.attestationObject` are correct.

When I call `navigator.credentials.get()` I get

[image]

which show a list of all the "discoverable public keys" I registered during my tests.

Now I would like to delete all those [Client-side discoverable Credential
/ resident keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#client-side-discoverable-public-key-credential-source) , is there any way to delete those from Google Chrome UI, or commmand line or API?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows 11 22H2 (the fall release), you can use Chrome 109 (chrome://settings/passkeys) to delete individual passkeys.

Comment: It's curious I'm on macOS Monterey 12.6.1 and Chrome  107.0.5304.121 and chrome://settings/passkeys says "These passkeys are stored in **Windows Hello** on this computer. They aren't saved to your Google Account." , I can delete the passkeys from here, but I wonder about the "Windows Hello" message

Comment: I updated to Chrome 108.0.5359.71 and now it says "These passkeys are only saved on this device. They aren't saved to your Google Account."  so they removed the reference to Windows Hello in the latest

Comment: On windows, I successfully followed the steps from https://super-unix.com/superuser/how-to-remove-webauthn-credentials-from-onboard-tpm-on-win10-device/
No UI at the moment and quite boring, but works fine